# Show that $rank(A)+rank(B) \leq n$, when $A,B$ are $2$ matrices of size $n \times n$, and $AB=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, matrix-rank

Question from homework in Linear Algebra:

Let $A,B$ be two matrices of size $n \times n$ such that $AB=0$.

Show that: $rank(A) + rank(B)  \le  n$ .

It probably has something to do with the dim of the null space or column space but I can't put things together from what we've learned...

Please help..
Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** show that $\operatorname{Im}(B)\subset \ker A$ and a well-known formula linking the rank and the dimension of the kernel of a matrix with the dimension of the underlying space.

Comment: when you say Ker(A) you mean Null Space ?
when you say Image sapce(B) you mean Column Space? we haven't learned the term Image space...

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. What is the notation used?

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. Now I understand the way to the solution. lest say that column space of B is C(B) and null space of A is N(A) .For showing that $C(B) \subset N(A)$,  Is it enough to just say that because $ AB=0 $, then for each vector $ v \in C(B) : A∗v=0 $, therefor foreach $ v \in C(B) : v \in N(A) $,  therefor $ C(B) \subset N(A) $? @DavideGiraudo

Answer (score 0):

One can also use the inequality $rank(AB) \geq rank(B)-nul(A)$ which is true for all square matrices A nad B. By the rank-nullity theorem, we have $nul(A)= n - rank(A)$, so

$$
\begin{align}
 0=rank(AB) &\geq rank(B)-nul(A)\\
            &\geq rank(B)-n+rank(A)
\end{align}
$$
Which after rearrangement gives the desired inequality.